# Grunt not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, configuration, gruntjs, bower

grunt server --force is not working and throughing below errors.

```
c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could no
t find 'grunt' (>= 0) among 24 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spe
c'
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in
 `gem'
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/bin/grunt:22:in `<main>'
```

Problem caused after restarting the PC. I have tried below commands.

```
gem uninstall grunt
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install
```

I am using window-8 OS.

Comment: Are you using bundler? Is it in your gemfile?

Comment: dont know. how can i get to know this ?

Comment: look in your app root for a file called `gemfile`. maybe add a tag for your rails version. http://railscasts.com/episodes/201-bundler

Comment: there is a file named "gemfile" but how can i add a tag. i am not a programmer so didnt know all these things. also nothing is happing when i put bower install command.